# Div not changing on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created a webpage that have some big `div`s in it.

I have a button on that page. On the click of that button I want the current `div` to change and bring the next `div` up.

I have written some code but unfortunately it's not working :(

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tutorial">
    <p class="heading">Tell us about yourself</p>
    <div class="body">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="full_name">What's your full name?</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="about">Describe yourself:</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="about" name="about" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Share you hobbies, interests and more about yourself"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="900px" height="60px"></td>
                <td>
                    <button id="next" class="btn">Next</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tutorial hidden">
    <p class="heading">Tell us about yourself!</p>
    <div class="body">Body</div>
</div>
<div class="tutorial hidden">
    <p class="heading">Tell us about yourself!</p>
    <div class="body">Body</div>
</div>
<div class="tutorial hidden">
    <p class="heading">Tell us about yourself!</p>
    <div class="body">Body</div>
</div>
<div class="tutorial hidden">
    <p class="heading">Tell us about yourself!</p>
    <div class="body">Body</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    var tutorials = $("div.tutorial");
    var idNumber = 1;
    tutorials.each(function () {
        $(this).attr("id", idNumber);
        idNumber++;
    });

    var nextButton = $("#next");

    $(nextButton).on('click', function () {
        var currentTutorial = $("div.tutorial").not(".hidden");
        var currentTutorialId = currentTutorial.prop("id");
        currentTutorial.addClass("hidden");
        var nextTutorialId = currentTutorialId++;
        var nextDiv = null;
        if ($("div.tutorial").is("#" + nextTutorialId)) {
            var nextDiv = $("div.tutorial");
        }
        nextDiv.removeClass("hidden");
    });


});
```

*Removed CSS to shorten the question's length. :)*

**What I want:**
I want the next button to hide the current div and bring up the very next div after it.

**What I have done:**

```
var currentTutorial = $("div.tutorial").not(".hidden");
var currentTutorialId = currentTutorial.prop("id");
currentTutorial.addClass("hidden");
var nextTutorialId = currentTutorialId++;
var nextDiv = null;
if ($("div.tutorial").is("#" + nextTutorialId)) {
    var nextDiv = $("div.tutorial");
}
nextDiv.removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: didnt get your question

Comment: are you going to have a next button on every tutorial section or only one?

Comment: Keep the next button out of your `div.tutorial` else it will be hidden after first time you will click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select by `id`, however I don't see any `id` for the `.tutorial` divs. However, you could simply use the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) jQuery function to get the `nextSibling` of the current div. You also have to make sure that there's at least one div without the `.hidden` class initially.

E.g.

```
$('div.tutorial:not(.hidden)').addClass('hidden').next().removeClass('hidden');
```

You need to remove the id from your buttons and instead use a class and change your selector for the click binding. **As sugessted by @koala_dev**.

Comment: what a nice and clean solution! If i would have another upvote I would gave that up to you!

Comment: it brokes after placing the button on all the divs more than once!

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, Could you give an example, I am not sure that I understand what you mean by "placing the button on all the divs more than once"

Comment: I mean that if I add the next button on all the `div.tutorial`s then it doesn't change the div after one time

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui you need to remove the id from your buttons and instead use a class and change your selector for the click binding

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui , The `id` property must be unique for each elements in the DOM. Keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `prev()` and `next()` functions like

```
 $(nextButton).on('click', function () {
        var currentTutorial = $("div.tutorial").not(".hidden");
        var currentTutorialId = currentTutorial.prop("id");
        currentTutorial.addClass("hidden");

        currentTutorial.next('div').show();

         nextDiv.removeClass("hidden");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but @plalx gave a nice solution!